# pass form input value to action

Tags: html, forms, variables, action, textinput

I have a page (module-access.php).

On the page I have a form with one text input field. I'd like to set whatever is typed in this field to be part of the form's action.

```
<form action="module-access.php?company=THE-USERS-INPUT" method="post" name="company" id="company">
Company Name: <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" VALUE="Go"></FORM>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the input name from textfield to company and the action type to GET

```
<form id="myform" action="module-access.php" method="GET">
    Company Name: <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why? Does it matter whether it's passed in the `POST` or `GET`? You can always just use `REQUEST`.

If it does matter then you'll need to use JavaScript to modify the action before you `POST` the form. Not very hard to do.